# how can I change textColorPrimary in a Apptheme

Tags: android

I want to change textColorPrimary I try this ;

In v21/styles.xml I add ;

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

But,It's doesn't work what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it in normal style file also. You can look it under value folder or create a new one to serve device below api 21.

Answer (score -1):

Change it in normal 'styles.xml'

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```